# How to get response my below api when using retrofit?

Tags: android, json, android-recyclerview, retrofit

I got json response when using volley or bridge , but i can"t get response with using retrofit library 
below is my API MY API 
  https://api.myjson.com/bins/u88lj

My Code given  Below

```
private void loadJSON(){
    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("https://api.learn2crack.com")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();
    RequestInterface request = retrofit.create(RequestInterface.class);
    Call<JSONResponse> call = request.getJSON();
    call.enqueue(new Callback<JSONResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<JSONResponse> call, Response<JSONResponse> response) {

            JSONResponse jsonResponse = response.body();
            System.out.println("jsonResponse------------------"+jsonResponse );
            System.out.println("cancel()------------------" +jsonResponse.getAndroid());
            System.out.println("response------------------" +response);
            data = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(jsonResponse.getAndroid()));
            adapter = new DataAdapter(data);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<JSONResponse> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.d("Error",t.getMessage());
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: What have you tried ? put your code and error

Comment: Share your code and error log

Comment: **DIY** like this:
1) Go to [how to make a pojo class from json response](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/), 
2) Paste your response over there and enter package and class name,
3) Choose target language as Java,
4) Source type as Json,
5) Annotation style  as Gson,
6) Click **Preview**,
7) Copy and paste those classes to your app package
8) Use `List<RestResponse>` as parameterized type to `Call`.

Comment: @Shameem Ahsan ,could you check my answer please ?

Answer (score 0):

According to  your json data .You json is `JSONArray` .

Else ,you will have error

> **Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY**

You can use `List<JSONResponse>` instead of `JSONResponse` in your code .

```
Call<List<JSONResponse>> call = request.getJSON();
```

Answer (score 0):

check out this

in interface make changes like this

```
public interface RetrofitInterface{
  @GET("url tail part")
    Call<ApiResponses> getApiResponses();
}
```

add a new model class

```
 public class ApiResponses {

        List<String> messages;
        List<ResultDetails> resultDetailsList;

        public ApiResponses(List<String> messages, List<ResultDetails> resultDetailsList) {
            this.messages = messages;
            this.resultDetailsList = resultDetailsList;
        }

        public List<String> getMessages() {
            return messages;
        }

        public List<ResultDetails> getResultDetailsList() {
            return resultDetailsList;
        }



        public static class ResultDetails{

            String name;
            String alpha2_code;
            String alpha3_code;

            public ResultDetails(String name, String alpha2_code, String alpha3_code) {
                this.name = name;
                this.alpha2_code = alpha2_code;
                this.alpha3_code = alpha3_code;
            }

            public String getName() {
                return name;
            }

            public String getAlpha2_code() {
                return alpha2_code;
            }

            public String getAlpha3_code() {
                return alpha3_code;
            }
        }
    }
```

in main activity add this

```
 Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("https://api.learn2crack.com")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();

retrofit.create(RetrofitInterface.class);
retrofit.getApiResponses().enqueue(new Callback<ApiResponses>{
 @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<ApiResponses> call, Response<ApiResponses> response) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<ApiResponses> call, Throwable t) {

                call.cancel();
                t.printStackTrace();
            }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use base url  "https://api.myjson.com" like this

```
    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("https://api.myjson.com")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();
    RequestInterface request = retrofit.create(RequestInterface.class);
```

Create Interface like this

```
public interface RequestInterface {
@GET("bins/u88lj")
Call<JSONResponse> getJSON();

}
```

To parse your response in json like this

```
public class JSONResponse {

@SerializedName("RestResponse")
private RestResponse RestResponse;


public JSONResponse.RestResponse getRestResponse() {
    return RestResponse;
}

public void setRestResponse(JSONResponse.RestResponse restResponse) {
    RestResponse = restResponse;
}

public class RestResponse {
    @SerializedName("messages")
    private ArrayList<String> messages;

    @SerializedName("result")
    private ArrayList<Result> result;


    public ArrayList<String> getMessages() {
        return messages;
    }

    public void setMessages(ArrayList<String> messages) {
        this.messages = messages;
    }

    public ArrayList<Result> getResult() {
        return result;
    }

    public void setResult(ArrayList<Result> result) {
        this.result = result;
    }
}


public class Result {
    @SerializedName("name")
    private String name;
    @SerializedName("alpha2_code")
    private String alpha2_code;
    @SerializedName("alpha3_code")
    private String alpha3_code;


    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getAlpha2_code() {
        return alpha2_code;
    }

    public void setAlpha2_code(String alpha2_code) {
        this.alpha2_code = alpha2_code;
    }

    public String getAlpha3_code() {
        return alpha3_code;
    }

    public void setAlpha3_code(String alpha3_code) {
        this.alpha3_code = alpha3_code;
    }
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Example.java

```
public class Example {

    @SerializedName("RestResponse")
    @Expose
    private RestResponse restResponse;

    public RestResponse getRestResponse() {
        return restResponse;
    }

    public void setRestResponse(RestResponse restResponse) {
        this.restResponse = restResponse;
    }

}
```

RestResponse.java

```
public class RestResponse {

    @SerializedName("messages")
    @Expose
    private List<String> messages = null;
    @SerializedName("result")
    @Expose
    private List<Result> result = null;

    public List<String> getMessages() {
        return messages;
    }

    public void setMessages(List<String> messages) {
        this.messages = messages;
    }

    public List<Result> getResult() {
        return result;
    }

    public void setResult(List<Result> result) {
        this.result = result;
    }

}
```

Result.java

```
public class Result {

    @SerializedName("name")
    @Expose
    private String name;
    @SerializedName("alpha2_code")
    @Expose
    private String alpha2Code;
    @SerializedName("alpha3_code")
    @Expose
    private String alpha3Code;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getAlpha2Code() {
        return alpha2Code;
    }

    public void setAlpha2Code(String alpha2Code) {
        this.alpha2Code = alpha2Code;
    }

    public String getAlpha3Code() {
        return alpha3Code;
    }

    public void setAlpha3Code(String alpha3Code) {
        this.alpha3Code = alpha3Code;
    }

}
```

Api client :

```
public class ApiClient {

    public static final String BASE_URL = "https://api.myjson.com/";
    private static Retrofit retrofit = null;


    public static Retrofit getClient() {
        if (retrofit==null) {
            retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build();
        }
        return retrofit;
    }
}
```

Api interface :

```
public interface ApiInterface {

    @POST("login.php")
    @FormUrlEncoded
    Call<users> getTopRatedMovies(@Field("uemail") String uemail, @Field("upassword") String upassword);

    @GET("bins/u88lj")
    Call<Example> getResponse();

    @Multipart
    @POST("create_event1.php")
    Call<users> uploadImage(@Part MultipartBody.Part image , @Part("user_email") RequestBody email,  @Part("e_name") RequestBody name);

}
```

Main activity :

```
 Call<Example> call = apiService.getResponse();

        // Set up progress before call
        final ProgressDialog progressDoalog;
        progressDoalog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        progressDoalog.setMessage("Its loading....");
        progressDoalog.setTitle("Please wail while data is loading");
        // show it
        progressDoalog.show();



        call.enqueue(new Callback<Example>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<Example> call, Response<Example> response) {
                progressDoalog.dismiss();
                int statusCode = response.code();

                // String movies = response.body().getMessage();
                List<Result> restResponses = response.body().getRestResponse().getResult();

                Log.w("response",new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create().toJson(response));
                recyclerView.setAdapter(new MoviesAdapter(restResponses, R.layout.list_item_movie, getApplicationContext()));
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<Example> call, Throwable t) {
                progressDoalog.dismiss();
                // Log error here since request failed
                Log.e(TAG, t.toString());
            }
        });
```

Adapter :

```
public class MoviesAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MoviesAdapter.MovieViewHolder> {

    private List<Result> movies;
    private int rowLayout;
    private Context context;


    public static class MovieViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        LinearLayout moviesLayout;
        TextView movieTitle;
        TextView data;
        TextView movieDescription;
        TextView rating;


        public MovieViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);
            moviesLayout = (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.movies_layout);
            movieTitle = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.title);
            data = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.subtitle);
            movieDescription = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.description);
            rating = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.rating);
        }
    }

    public MoviesAdapter(List<Result> movies, int rowLayout, Context context) {
        this.movies = movies;
        this.rowLayout = rowLayout;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public MoviesAdapter.MovieViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,
                                                            int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(rowLayout, parent, false);
        return new MovieViewHolder(view);
    }


    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MovieViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        holder.movieTitle.setText(movies.get(position).getAlpha2Code());
        holder.data.setText(movies.get(position).getAlpha3Code());
        holder.movieDescription.setText(movies.get(position).getName());
//        holder.rating.setText(movies.get(position).getVoteAverage().toString());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return movies.size();
    }
}
```

Comment: Just create two layouts along with this. One having recyclerview and other it's custom row file.